# Chart vba suddenly getting error 1004?

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a piece of VBA code that was working before, but it gets error 1004 on name/xvalue/value recently. I am using excel 2010.

```
Sub LineChartTemp()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
'    i = series, j = start row, k = end row

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine

    Dim chart As chart
    Set chart = ActiveChart

    For i = 1 To 156
        j = (i - 1) * 13 + 1 + 1
        k = j + 12

'        two 1, one for name row, one for the minus 1, 13 is number of data points of each series

        chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        chart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & j & ":$C$" & j
        chart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$D$" & j & ":$D$" & k
        chart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$E$" & j & ":$E$" & k

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide a data sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Does your sheet name now have spaces?  If yes it needs to be in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I removed spaces in one sheet, It seems to work now